# Opening a Non-Password-Protected Access 2000 Database that Asks for a Username and Password

Tags: passwords, ms-access-2000

I'm trying to open a Microsoft Access 2000 .MDB file to migrate it, as it is currently being used by somebody's ten-year-old VB app that's fallen by the way side on an NT server and whose author is long gone. Back in September I copied the MDB file over to a nearby XP machine (because that has Access installed), and when it asked for a name and password, was able to open it then using those of the Windows XP account I was logged in as.

However, since I tried again in November, it suddenly will no longer accept that username/password pair and everyone swears noone has touched the machine. I've tried a blank username, the login/pass of the "Administrator" account on the NT server from which I got it, as well as all of those on the XP machine I previously opened it on.

I tried running a couple password-recovery apps on it such as [Rixler Access Password Recovery](http://www.rixler.com/de/access_password_recovery.htm) and [Nirsoft's "accesspv.exe"](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/accesspv.html), and they both say that the file is **not** password-protected. So it's not a "database" password per se, it just wants some account info and I have no idea even what username it wants.

I've read up on what I could find in the way of MDW files; finding 3 of such on the XP workstation, I tried renaming them all in case that's where it's trying to look for account names, but the result is also the same.

The half-broken VB app that it was built for is apparently still opening and using the database fine; alas I've not found its source code.

Anyone know what Access 2000 wants as far as credentials in a non-password-protected MDB file, and how to get back in?

Thanks.

Comment: Workgroup authentication? Maybe a linked database requires credentials?

Comment: How might one investigate such? I've tried copying over the entire directory, including the accompanying MDW file to no avail. Also when you double-click it on the original NT server, it doesn't even prompt you for credentials but says:

"You do not have the necessary permissions to use the 'E:\Path\To\file.MDB' object. Have your system administrator or the person who created this object establish the appropriate permissions for you."

If only.

Comment: You need to create a shortcut or batch file that includes the location of the mdw. You could also try opening an mdw, especially one that is not called system.mdw, if there is one. This may help http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305542

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with [MDB Tools](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/). That would have been pretty handy about five months ago.